# Sample [English] Dictionary SQL Script to populate table?

Tags: sql, dictionary, scripting, spell-checking

Does anyone know of a link to a reference on the web that contains a sample English dictionary word script, that can be used to populate a dictionary table in SQL Server?

I can handle a .txt or .csv file, or something similar.

Alternatively, I'm adding custom spellchecking functionality to my web apps...but I don't want to integrate the standard components.  If there are good references (with samples) on building a dictionary word checker, I'd love that too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Downloadable Dictionaries](http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php)

[GNU version of The Collaborative International Dictionary of English (XML)](http://www.ibiblio.org/webster/)

Answer (score 1):

I actually asked for the wrong thing, but I like the answer so far.
I really wanted a English word list for a spell checking application, that I can use to populate a table in SQL Server.

Here is one that I finally found, that is ok:
[English Word List](http://pages.prodigy.net/daleharris/speller.htm)

This one is even better: [Another English Word List](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/)

Answer (score 1):

As used on [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/main/s/scowl/scowl_6-2.3/wamerican-large.copyright) and [Ubuntu](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/scowl/scowl_6-2.1/wbritish.copyright):

[SCOWL (Spell Checker Oriented Word Lists)](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) is a collection of English word lists maintained by Kevin Atkinson...

Answer (score 0):

One dictionary you could use is the wordnet dictionary available from http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/